# Read a File from an App with the Same Package Name

Tags: android, xamarin

I have an app on the play store that I wrote with Java and Android Studio, and I'm looking to replace it with one written with C# and Xamarin.

Everything is going smoothly, except for one thing. My Xamarin code can't seem to read any files that the old Java based application has, that stores user settings and data.

I'm using the same package name, and I'm also using the same certificates to sign the application. I was assuming I would also have access to the same directory.

Here's how I save the file in Android Studio using the activity context:

```java
byte[] data = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
try (FileOutputStream stream = context.get().openFileOutput("file.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)) {
    stream.write(data);
}
```

Here's how I'm trying to read the file in C#

```cs
using (Stream stream = CustomClass.MainActivity.OpenFileInput("file.dat"))
{
    byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

The C# code doesn't see the file, and when using MainActivity.FileList() to enumerate all of the files, it doesn't show up there either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using the standard System.IO.File methods?

Comment: You could check the file first. Do you write the file correctly using java and save the file in internal storage?

Comment: @Jason I have tried to use the standard System.IO.File methods in the shared project, but with no luck

Answer (score 1):

```
        string tag = "myapp";
        var file = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "file.dat");

        if (file == null || !File.Exists(file))
        {
            Log.Warn(tag, "file not exists");
        }
        else
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file))
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
```

read official docs for more:
[File Storage and Access with Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/)

Since we need to run the debug apk often, also make sure to use the same `keystore` sign it, you can do it by configuring the debug keystore manually:

[image]

Comment: I've tried the standard System.IO.File methods with no luck. I'm starting to think that Xamarin deletes any existing packages and files that share the same package name as whatever you're deploying

Comment: it shouldn't.  Have you actually examined the file system to verify that these files are stored where you think they are?

Comment: Make sure your file does exist using Device File Explorer. Maybe you can check out the test project I uploaded here: https://github.com/lsanotes/q58278782

Comment: Just an update, but Visual Studio was deleting the files when it deployed the app. After installing the old version using Android Studio, I checked to make sure the files where there, which they were. Then, I deployed the new Xamarin version with Visual Studio, and the files were gone.

Comment: So you've configure the same debug keystore as in Android Studio?

Comment: Same debug keystore, and I sign the builds the same way for release as well. I also tried installing the APKs manually with adb, and it complains about the packages having a different signature. It's definitely the problem, I just can't figure out why they're different.

Comment: Have you tried the test project I uploaded here: https://github.com/lsanotes/q58278782.  Make sure manually config the debug keystore and Visual Studio do use the configured keystore to sign the debug apk.

Comment: I've also updated the answer with more info on how to configure the debug keystore.